# I`m sure is a quick fix, but it does not seem to work like this

Tags: php, html, mysql, echo

The problem is that the $prenume echoing works, while $comentarii doesn`t. I tried with and without quotes. If I echo $comentarii in the while loop, it echoes. I only have 1 line of text to retreive from database. Please help! Thank you !

```
$gaseste_elevul = "SELECT prenume_elev, comentarii
FROM elevi
WHERE kod_utilizator=1";
    $gaseste_elevul_query = mysql_query($gaseste_elevul);

    while($elevul = mysql_fetch_array($gaseste_elevul_query))
    {
        $prenume = $elevul['prenume_elev'];
        $comentarii = $elevul['comentarii'];


    }
    if($comentarii = NULL)
    {
        echo "Momentan nu aveti informari pentru $prenume!";
    }

    else 
      {
    echo "Mai jos aveti informarile pentru $prenume:";  
    echo "$comentarii";

  }//sfarsit else
```

I also tried to do the whole if($comentarii=NULL) in the while loop, to no result.

Comment: It's a simple syntax error, but I can't help adding this obligatory line: **Switch to PDOs, mysql_* stuff is deprecated and insecure!**

Comment: I will...but i dont have the time to learn them now. this needs to be done by 5 september... Thanks for the heads-up though

Comment: If it needs to be done by 5 September, then you're already late... so why not switch to pdo/mysqli anyway

Comment: I`m not late :D those are the final touches ;) Will do after 5 sep...its a big website....

Comment: You realise that today is 29th September? I know it's easy to lose track of time when working on a big project

Comment: ah i meant october, SORRRYYYY!

Comment: You know that the MySQL extension is outdated, don't you?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a simple typo and won't be of any use to anyone else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
if($comentarii = NULL)
```

to

```
if($comentarii == NULL)
```

Your first statement sets the `$comentarii` to `null`, and that's why it doesn't echoing anything.

Comment: works! Thank you a lot ! I was sure i am overlooking something..I`m kindof tired. Thank you! Cannot accept your answer for 11 minutes but will soon ;) Thanks!

Comment: No problems, such misstakes happens :)